# Add/Remove Rows and Columns with Drag n Drop functionality

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, tableview

Anyone can suggest which View will be better to achieve this? (RecyclerView, TableView or any other View)

1. Add/Remove Rows
2. Add/Remove Columns
3. Drag n Drop Views from right view to this view.

P.S. currently i'm using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and i can Drag n Drop Views from right View to recyclerView but facing issue while adding/removing Rows and Columns.

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Add and remove Rows and Columns]
[image: Drag and Drop views from right View to this View]

Comment: I don't think you'll easily achieve such kind of UI by just using SDK components. You'll need to create *Compound ViewGroup* or *Custom ViewGroup* for that.

Comment: can you help further?